# AWS S3 batch operation job max duration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Out of curiosity, what is the maximum duration for a job in S3 Batch operations ?
It seems it is not written anywhere in the doc ...

Also, is there a way to calculate an estimate of the duration when creating a job in S3 batch operation ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There shouldn't be any max duration, the job will run until it is complete.
2. For duration, it depends on the operation being used and the characteristics of the objects. One possible way to estimate for a large job is to run a test job with a sample of the keys